# Are pictures on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

I am looking for **open-licensed** pictures (beyond Google Images) of:

- the 2012 Uzbekistan Cup
- the كارنده چال‎ village
- John Bilsborrow
- the H7N2 virus

Would each of these questions be on-topic or off-topic?

Comment: Imo, asking for a repository or a dataset with open-licensed images, would be on-topic. For example, one could give an detailed answer on how to search on flickr for open-licensed images.

Comment: The H7N2 virus will not show up on Flickr, rather in a specialized medical database. The كارنده چال‎ village pictures might be found in a national archive. Same for the other questions, each would command different answers. I guess.

Comment: Yeap. That's why I said "for example". If I want something more common, like training a code to recognize horses' images, Flickr could do the job, but images with cancer will not. However, as I said, for me it is on-topic, but we should be careful on users answers, because not all people check (or even know) the licenses there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions asking for any open data are on topic. It doesn't matter if the data is in the form of tables, spreadsheets, images, videos, or other formats. The key issue is that it is a data hunt for open content.

Comment: I guess that only executable files have a better site: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com :-)