# Is source code on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

So [images are on-topic](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229/are-pictures-on-topic-or-off-topic). How about source code?

I actually have a real-life need to find the source code for some product (which is presumably open source but difficult to find).

Often I have to find the source code of a driver of small library that moved hosting several times, and it can be very tricky to find the up-to-date source code. Pretty much the same challenges as when looking for other types of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since we currently allow data requests for other kinds of content such as [images](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/images) and [corpora](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corpora), I see no reason why [data hunts for source code](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/3941/where-can-i-find-the-source-code-for-liferay-sync) would not be welcome at the moment.

However once [Open Source SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source) launches, we might need to reevaluate.

Answer (score 0):

Since open source is handled by StackOverflow's [Open Source tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/open-source), I suggest we focus on open content (whether data or images).

Comment: Unfortunately such questions would be off-topic on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic Actually most questions with the Open Source tag are getting closed and downvoted it seems.